# MVC 2 model not getting textbox value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using MVC2 and I'm having trouble getting the value of a texbox.

My view code is:

```
<% for (int i=0;i<Model.Count();i++) { %>
<%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Quantity)%>
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Quantity, new { @class = "quantity", @maxlength = "3", @size = "2" })%>
<%}%>

<input type="submit" value="Actualizar" name="update" class="btnUpdateCart" />
```

Clicking to update button triggers this function:

```
[BrowserCache(PreventBrowserCaching = true)]
    public void UpdateCart(CartItem[] items)
      {
           Some code
      }
```

The problem is that at this point my CartItem[] doesn't have the Quantity set. I'm new at this tecnologie, i'm sure i'm missing something really silly...

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok
so what you need to look at  this(always gets me out of trouble

**public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(FormCollection formCollection)**

FormCollection -> will return collection of all form stuff any field that is passed along to the controler via request, so you can hook this up and see what is passed along.

still this does not answer your question lets see

//this line will render hidden field with some kind of value (is this filled in?)

```
<%:Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Quantity)%>
```

// why do you render text box for the same field? this will take what value is set in hidden field

```
<%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Quantity, new { @class = "quantity", @maxlength = "3", @size = "2" })%>
```

So my answer is remove the hidden field and it should work...

Comment: It worked! thx! This wasn't my code and it's my first time with MVC so I am a little lost.